# css drop down menu falls behind google chart

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index, google-visualization

I've tried everything I could think of.
I've tried playing around with the positioning and the z-indexes but no matter what I do the drop down menu still goes behind the google chart. It works with fire fox but not google chrome or IE. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Here is the drop down css:

```
#deluxeMenu
{
    overflow:visible;
    z-index:9999999;
}

ul#deluxeMenu 
{
    display:block;font-size:0;zoom:1;float: left;
    overflow:visible;
    position: relative;
    z-index:99999;
}

ul#deluxeMenu ul{display:none; z-index:100;}
ul#deluxeMenu li:hover>*{display:block}


ul#deluxeMenu >li:hover{position:relative; z-index:100;}

ul#deluxeMenu ul{
    position: absolute;left:-1px;top:98%;z-index:100;}

ul#deluxeMenu ul ul{
    position: absolute;left:98%;top:-2px;z-index:100;}

ul#deluxeMenu,ul#deluxeMenu ul{
    margin:0px;list-style:none;padding:0px;background-   color:#353535;border-width:0px;border-style:none;border-color:#C0AF62; z-index:100;}

ul#deluxeMenu ul{
/*width:145px;padding:0;*/
overflow:visible;
}

ul#deluxeMenu li{
display:block;margin:0;font-size:0;float:left; overflow:visible;
}

ul#deluxeMenu a:active, ul#deluxeMenu a:focus {outline-style:none; z-index:100;}

ul#deluxeMenu a,ul#deluxeMenu li.dis a:hover{
display:block;vertical-align:middle;background-color:#353535;background-image:url(blank.gif);border-width:1px 0px 1px 0px;border-style:solid;border-color:#3F3F3F #333333 #292929 #333333;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;padding:10px 12px 10px 10px;font:normal 13px calibri,arial,tahoma;color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;cursor:pointer;





}
    ul#deluxeMenu ul li {float:none; overflow:visible;}

    ul#deluxeMenu ul a,ul#deluxeMenu ul li.dis a:hover{
text-align:left;white-space:nowrap;


}
    ul#deluxeMenu li:hover>a
    {
background-image:url(back-over.gif);border-color:#3F3F3F #333333 #292929 #333333;border-style:solid;font:normal 13px calibri,arial,tahoma;color: #FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;


}
    ul#deluxeMenu li.dis a{color: #AAAAAA !important;}

    ul#deluxeMenu img{
border: none;vertical-align: middle;margin-right:20px;}
    ul#deluxeMenu img.over{display:none}
    ul#deluxeMenu li.dis a:hover img.over{display:none !important}
    ul#deluxeMenu li.dis a:hover img.def {display:inline !important}
    ul#deluxeMenu li:hover > a img.def  {display:none;}
    ul#deluxeMenu li:hover > a img.over {display:inline;}
    ul#deluxeMenu ul span{background-image:none;padding-right:20px;}
```

Here is the php file for the web page:

```
<body> 


<div style="position:relative;">
<!-- Deluxe Menu -->                    
<div id = "box">
<ul id="deluxeMenu">
<?php include('populateMenu.php')?>
</ul>
</div>                              
<div id="chart_div">
</div>


                            <?php  closeDatabase($db); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you self embedded the flash file in your html? In that case, try to add `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">` to the object-tag.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you applied `z-index` to the navigation div, but did you also
apply it to the `chart_div`? Try adding `z-index:1` to `#chart_div` and see
if that helps.

Comment: I did some research and apparently it is Google Chrome's fault. Apparently Google Chrome has some z-index complications at times!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, not with menu, but just overlapping with another elements, so this might be helpful I think

the chart's div always has a css style `position: relative`. like

```
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px; position: relative;">
```

so, I just appended my element to this div and gave it a attr `position:absolute` with `z-index` of 10 or smth, so it worked

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Delete one 9 from `z-index`. You should get `z-index:999999;`